# printk() before console_int() in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I am looking at the Linux kernel flow, where I came across `early_printk`, 
which is used for `printk` before console is initialized.

In my case `early_printk` is not enabled and still I am getting prints with `printk` before `console_init`.

From where i am getting these prints?

Comment: *"I am getting prints with printk before console_init"* -- You're confused by what you're looking at.  All the printk() output is buffered.  When the console is actually initialized, then the contents of that buffer are actually displayed.  IOW the console output is not in realtime.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237673/why-is-kernel-boot-too-late/24337389#24337389 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431266/how-to-optimize-u-boot-to-kernel-hand-off-code/24461977#24461977

Answer (score 0):

If you see the kernel source code as below, even though `early_printk` is disabled, kernel message needs to prints in scenario like `panic` etc.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK
extern asmlinkage __printf(1, 2)
void early_printk(const char *fmt, ...);
#else   
static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
void early_printk(const char *s, ...) { }
```

From the above, its enable or not `early_printk()` is called and in `disable` case it will be called if any `early_panic()` is there.

`early_panic()` means if kernel is trying to recover some problem like below and if not then `panic()` will happen and it will `die`.

```
[40462.661285] Attribute myarray: Invalid permissions 0700
                                                       |
here I tried to give permission to `variable` to verify whether `panic` happens or not.
```